# Excel: Copy-paste rows in between sheets depending on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, criteria

*Thank you for the comments so far, it has helped me formulate my question better/differently.*

I have two sheets, **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**.
**Sheet1** contains ~100,000 rows with 5 columns and **Sheet2** should contain a subgroup of **Sheet1**, depending if the rows in **Sheet1** contain certain values in certain columns.

This is the code I have so far. Somehow the VBA doesn't give me any error, but the code also doesn't run, which makes it difficult to find a possible solution. Anyone any ideas?

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim r As Integer
Dim cell As Range
r = 2
For Each cell In Selection
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1)) = False Then
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3) = "Product1" or "Product2" Then
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5) = "2011" or "2012" Then
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4) > 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=activesheet.Rows(r)
                r = r + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put a filter on your table in Sheet1?

Comment: @iDevlop I just added some code with some explanation.

Comment: @Xophmeister I'm not sure if that is possible, because this filtering is just one of the many things I do with both sheets. I need to think about this one.

Comment: I think you need to think more about how you want to architect the solution before you start coding. For example, do you want to insert/delete rows or just show/hide them (it isn't clear in your question)? The code will be quite different for each. Other questions come to mind: can a company have three products? why are there two instances of the row `CompanyA; Amsterdam; Product1; 0`?

Comment: Thank you, yes you're right. I was thinking yesterday, it might not need to be so complicated. I have a database-like Sheet1 and I only want to 'correct' rows from there to go onto Sheet2. With correct I mean all rows with a certain value for certain columns. I'll rewrite my question and remove the hiding code which has nothing to do with my answer I am realizing now.

Comment: I've changed the code entirely and now the code doesn't run but also doesn't give an error. When I click on the button to which I assign above code, nothing happens, the developer toolbar to "stop" and "play" a macro doesn't even show.

Answer (score 0):

For such consolidations my first bet would be a Pivot table; in your case

- Company & City at the vertical
- product at the horizontal (if not too many)
- count or sum of value inside

plus eventually a filter to exclude empty key fields.

If you arrange your sheet1 so that there is only one header line in row 1, you can select entire columns (say $A:$D) as pivot table input range, and any additional rows will be included in the Pivot upon refresh.

Of course, the Pivot table can be sorted, filtered, subtotaled etc. etc.

Comment: I only need to have the values to input them into a different sheet. From there I'll do different kinds of analyses on it that a PivotTable can't do. Unless I can get the data I want from a PivotTable and insert that in a sheet? To make myself clear :), **Sheet2** isn't my final sheet, so to speak.